# Laravel not rendering sample blog, permissions to directories already given

Tags: php, linux, laravel, apache

I'm testing Laravel on a Arch Linux ARM, to which I'm connecting through SSH.

Going throughout the [Laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#installing-laravel)
I created a new blog. So far so good.

The [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation#configuration) mention the following:

> After installing Laravel, you should configure your web server's document / web root to be the public directory. The index.php in this directory serves as the front controller for all HTTP requests entering your application.

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.

This [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58725/how-do-we-know-that-a-directory-is-apache-writable) says that 'writable by my webserver' means that it must be writable by the user/group which   is running apache. I was able to get the group that apache is running from using
`ps -ef | grep httpd | grep -v grep`.

The user turned out to be *http*. I checked both **/etc/group** and **/etc/password** and the user and group exist with the same name. So I changed the permissions of both **bootstrap/cache** and the directories inside **storage** with

```
    sudo chown http bootstrap/cache/
    sudo chown -R http storage
    sudo chgrp http bootstrap/cache/
    sudo chgrp -R http storage
```

And gave writting permissions to the *http* group, I realize that this is overkill, since permissions are additive but I still had to try.

```
    sudo chmod g+w bootstrap/cache/
    sudo chmod -R g+w storage/
```

I've read plenty of threads and most of them mention Virtual Hosts so I thought I might as well attempt that, I went throughout the [Arch Apache wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server)

> If you want to have more than one host, uncomment the following line in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

> > Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

> To test the virtual hosts on your local machine, add the virtual names to your /etc/hosts file:

> > 127.0.0.1 domainname1.dom

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/srv/httpd/blog/public"
      ServerName www.mytest.com
    </VirtualHost>
```

And on my local Ubuntu computer I have `<my_Linux_ARM_IP>   www.mytest.com` on **/etc/hosts/**

So, whenever I type **[www.mytest.com](http://www.mytest.com)** on my local computer I get.

[image: Laravel not rendering]

I changed the DocumentRoot to test a simple and pure index.html file and it rendered just fine, so I figure the issue is with Laravel.

I was able to manage all this on a local WAMP system beforehand, write the vhosts, change the hosts file so that localhost points to the vhost. And blog rendered just fine.

So it's not Laravel but Apache and the LAN connection? I'm not sure where to go next. Should I read more Apache docs? Should I read more Laravel docs? Should I read more networking stuff? If so, could someone provide some good resources?

Thank you.

Comment: its a web server misconfiguration, so apache related

Comment: Hey @lagbox, are you possitive about this? Even if a simple index.html renders just fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @langbox.
I just followed the steps of this [wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Apache_HTTP_Server#PHP), I chose to use **libphp** and now it renders correctly.